# MVC Remote validation - transfer of entered data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

How to pass form data to remote mvc validation? Here is my model:

```
[Remote(action: "VerifyContinousOfReservation", controller: "Reservation", 
AdditionalFields = nameof(EndOfReservation))]
public DateTime StartOfReservation { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

[Remote(action: "VerifyContinousOfReservation", controller: "Reservation", 
AdditionalFields = nameof(StartOfReservation))]
public DateTime EndOfReservation { get; set;} = DateTime.Now;
```

Here is my controller:

```
 [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public IActionResult VerifyContinousOfReservation(string StartOfReservation, string EndOfReservation) 
    {

        var start = StartOfReservation;
        var end = EndOfReservation;


        return Json(true);
    }
```

I want to know what user send from input and check that there is no reservation in this data range. But start and end is null.

I don't know if I'm taking the right approach.
I have a JSON file with reserved dates. I want to use validation to check if the date range specified by the user does not contain a reserved date.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote validation"?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core, or ASP.NET MVC-for-.NET Framework?

Comment: "But start and end is null." - that's impossible: `DateTime` values _cannot_ be `null`.

Comment: [Remote] attribute - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0